# Magento migration from single store to multistore. Redirects

Tags: magento

I have 1 website for now. Its URL is www.test.com, for example.
I want to create second website on the same domain adding store codes to URLs. So my URLs will be

```
www.test.com/first/
www.test.com/second/
```

But as I can see all my previous URLs will show 404 on their open. So if I open

```
www.test.com/product.html
```

it will show 404. It is not good because I loose my SEO.
How can I create redirects so if user opens

```
www.test.com/product.html
```

he will be automatically redirected to default website, like

```
www.test.com/first/product.html
```

Shall I have any issues with such redirects? (Like API will not work)
Or is it possible for URL

```
www.test.com/product.html
```

to show product from default website, if exists?

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a very good system for SEO.

For Rewrite Management these are the steps:

1.Loginto Admin.
2.Move mouse over Catalog and you will find a drop down.
3 Select URL Rewrite management.

Catalog >> UrlRewrite Management

4.Then click on ADD URL Rewrite Button.

5.Then on next screen select custom from option provided

Create URL Rewrite : Select Custom

Now following important fields and values that should go:

1. Request Path (Old URL ) Target Path ( New URL )  redirect (Permanent 301).

Note : This approach will be good if you have few products but if you have too many product then some .htaccess rule is recommended.